# PMIC MIC23451 operating voltage range

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, pmic

I am using Microchip [SOM](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/ds60001521a.pdf) module in my project. Not using all the things in the SOM.

So we are redesigning the board with necessary components for my application.

Below is block diagram shows the main power flow. Output from PMIC1 ([MIC23451](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MIC23451)) is connected to PMIC2 ([MIC2800](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MIC2800)).

The input voltage range of [PMIC1](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MIC23451) **is 2.7 to 5.5 V** and in my board a **3.8 V 5 A** rail is free.

As per my knowledge I can use the 3.8 V 5 A rail as an input for [PMIC1](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MIC23451).

In the [reference design](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAMA5D27-SOM1-Kit1-Users-Guide-DS50002667C.pdf) (page 12)  **PMIC1 is powered with a 5 V**.

May I know can I go ahead with 3.8 V input for PMIC1?

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn’t you be? Where lies your doubts?

Comment: No doubts. As per my understanding I can run it on 3.8V 5A,but just double confirming from experts whether I can run at 3.8V 5A input or not.May I know your thoughts

Comment: As long as the logic levels are the same as the supply... But 3.8V is a weird one, you might end up with a lot of extra buffers just to translate the logic levels to 3.3V/5V.

Comment: Why does it say 180R below the coils, is it ESR? What are those for anyway, are they actually ferrites or such?

Comment: @Lundin,the main IC(SAMA5D27C-D1G-CU) is working at 3.3V rail

Comment: So why not use that one also? What's your reason not too - too much current? In that case pick a beefier regulator.